# Repair creep does not repair rampart

Tags: javascript, screeps

The following code prints out "rampart", and but the creep is just standing still and not repairing. It uses the snippet mentioned in the docs. According to the docs, structures can be repaired and rampart is a structure. What's wrong?

```
module.exports = function(creep) {
    var target = creep.pos.findNearest(Game.MY_STRUCTURES, {
        filter: function(object) {
            return object.hits < object.hitsMax;
    }
    });
    if(target) {
        console.log("_________" + target.structureType);
        creep.moveTo(target);
        creep.repair(target);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your creep has enough energy in him to perform repair operation (it consumes energy on every tick).

By the way, you can check the result code of a method to debug such cases:

```
console.log( creep.repair(target) );
```

It will output `-6` to console which means [`Game.ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_ENERGY`](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php#repair).

Comment: Thank you, that should do it.

Comment: Nice, those error codes will indeed help a lot. Btw, using Chrome, I have a visual bug of console.log, where the time and my output overlap (hence I'm using "_______"). Is this a known bug?

Comment: No, please send a screenshot to us at support@screeps.com